# Error While creating a new database in Odoo

Tags: postgresql, odoo

I get the following error while creating a new database from Odoo database manager:

```
OperationalError: could not read file "base/1/11814": Input/output error
```

I have no idea why this has been happening. Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: See the logs for more information about the error.